# ansible invoke variable forming from first variable file and string and listed in second variables file

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-awx

We have two variable files, the first files carries constant and the second variables from the output generated.

firstfile.yml

```
---
prefix: test
```

secondfile.yml

```
---
test_variable: 12345
```

In we are want to call test_variable, but the formation of the variable should be concatenation from firstfile.yml and not `"{{ test_variable }}"`

Example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars: 

    constants: firstfile.yml
    variables: seconfile.yml

  vars_files:

    - [ "{{ constants }}, {{ variables }}"

  tasks:
    name: test_name
    field: "{{ prefix }}_variable"
```

Error: `'test_variable' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [debug](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html) module to display variable in Ansible.

You must quote each template expression brackets, not all. And if you want to include multiple variable files, you can use separate line for each file or use a list, should not combine 2 method.

Your playbook after modified:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars: 
    constants: firstfile.yml
    variables: secondfile.yml
  vars_files: ["{{ constants }}", "{{ variables }}"]
  tasks:
    - debug: var="{{ prefix }}_variable"
```

Result:

```
TASK: [debug var="{{ prefix }}_variable"] ************************************* 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "test_variable": "12345"
    }
}
```